# How to make the Open3D read the pandas DataFrame and generate points clouds in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, open3d

I extracted certain data from the original CSV file (which contains the XYZ coordinates) by using the following code
.

```
data=pd.read_csv("./assets/landmarks_frame0.csv",header=None,usecols=range(1,4))
print(data)
```

The printing output looks fine as below. Recall that the first (started with 0.524606), second and third columns correspond to the x,y and z coordinates.
[the snipped image of the pandas DataFrame extracted from the CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTMvL.png)

Meanwhile, my goal is to import the Open3D library and generate the points cloud based on the data extracted from the pandas. I read the Open3D documents (http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/tutorial/geometry/pointcloud.html) and wrote the script as follows

```
print("Load a ply point cloud, print it, and render it")
pcd = o3d.io.read_point_cloud(data,format="xyz")
print(pcd)
print(np.asarray(pcd.points))
o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([pcd],
                                  zoom=0.3412,
                                  front=[0.4257, -0.2125, -0.8795],
                                  lookat=[2.6172, 2.0475, 1.532],
                                  up=[-0.0694, -0.9768, 0.2024])
```

As shown in the second line

```
pcd = o3d.io.read_point_cloud(data,format="xyz")
```

I learned from the File IO document (http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/tutorial/geometry/file_io.html) and passed the first argument as the data to be processed into the points cloud. Besides, I set the second argument format to be 'xyz', which means each line contains [x, y, z], where x, y, and z are the 3D coordinates.

However, the error message indicates as follow.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [3], in <cell line: 4>()
      1 print("Load a ply point cloud, print it, and render it")
      2 # ply_point_cloud = o3d.data.PLYPointCloud()
      3 # pcd = o3d.io.read_point_cloud(data,format="xyz")
----> 4 pcd = o3d.io.read_point_cloud(data,format="xyz")
      6 print(pcd)
      7 print(np.asarray(pcd.points))

TypeError: read_point_cloud(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (filename: str, format: str = 'auto', remove_nan_points: bool = False, remove_infinite_points: bool = False, print_progress: bool = False) -> open3d.cpu.pybind.geometry.PointCloud

Invoked with:             1         2         3
0    0.524606  0.675098 -0.021419
1    0.524134  0.628257 -0.034960
2    0.524757  0.641571 -0.019187
3    0.518863  0.589718 -0.024071
4    0.523975  0.615806 -0.036730
..        ...       ...       ...
473  0.557430  0.553579  0.006053
474  0.563593  0.553342  0.006053
475  0.557327  0.544035  0.006053
476  0.551414  0.553678  0.006053
477  0.557613  0.563182  0.006053

[478 rows x 3 columns]; kwargs: format='xyz'
```

I would like to know how I should correctly import the data into the Open3D and generate the point cloud. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

Open3D supports NumPy arrays. So, firstly you have to convert your dataframe with XYZ coordinates to a NumPy array. This will allow you to convert the NumPy array to the Open3D point cloud. You can check the documentation  [(here)](http://www.open3d.org/docs/0.9.0/tutorial/Basic/working_with_numpy.html)  of Open3D for further details.

The important lines (of documentation) for the conversion of a NumPy array to an Open3D point cloud are given below:

```
# Pass xyz to Open3D.o3d.geometry.PointCloud and visualize
pcd = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
pcd.points = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(xyz)
```

Here, 'xyz' is the NumPy array.